# product->seName() not work and new products appear in category products but disappear in manage products page?

Tags: magento-1.9, products-management

i wanna get products from [shopsense.shopstyle.com](http://shopsense.shopstyle.com) using simplexml_load_file() method in that code:

```
class Shopsense_Shopstyle_ShopstyleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function indexAction(){

        $this->loadLayout();//app/design/adminhtml

        $this->_setActiveMenu('shopsense');
        $this->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock('core/text')
             ->setText('<h1>import products</h1>'));

               $block= $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('shopsense_shopstyle/adminhtml_adminblock')
                ->setTemplate('shopsense/adminblock.phtml');

 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$results=simplexml_load_file("http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=1761-25615319-5&offset=0&limit=1&format=xml");

foreach($results->products as $prod){
    foreach($prod as $pro){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $product
                        ->setStoreId(1) 
                        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
                        ->setAttributeSetId(9) 
                        ->setTypeId('simple') 
                        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) 
                        ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now'))

                        ->setSku($pro->id)
                        ->setName($pro->name) 
                        ->setWeight(4.000)
                        ->setStatus(1)
                        ->setTaxClassId(4)
                        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) 
                        ->setManufacturer(28)
                        ->setColor(24)
                        ->setNewsFromDate('10/26/2014') 
                        ->setNewsToDate('12/30/2014') 
                        ->setCountryOfManufacture('EG') 
                        ->setPrice(11.22) 
                        ->setCost(22.33) 
                        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) 
                        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') 
                        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014')
                        ->setMsrpEnabled(0) 
                        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1)
                        ->setMsrp(99.99)                    
                        ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
                        ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
                        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')

                        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
                        ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')

                        ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) 
                        ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)                      
                        ->setStockData(array(
                                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
                                           'manage_stock'=>1,
                                           'min_sale_qty'=>1,
                                           'max_sale_qty'=>2, 
                                           'is_in_stock' => 1,
                                           'qty' => 10
                                       )
                        )

                        ->setCategoryIds(array(21)); //assign product to categories
                    $product->save();

       }
   }

                $this->_addContent($block);
                $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

but i find the new products here [image: add products for new category page]
 [with out the name !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!] why??

and not found that products in manage products page here 
[image: manage products page]

Comment: Try to log the value of `$pro->name` and see what you receive.

Comment: i did that and it return the product name put when use $product->setName() i doesn`t find the product name ??

Comment: Just found something else.  `->setStoreId(1)`. That's not right. When creating a product you cannot set directly values for a store id. You have to fill in first the values for default values. So replace it with `->setStoreId(0)`. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you Marius that is the answer

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
             //   if(!$product->getIdBySku('newnew')){



//   try{
        $product
           ->setStoreId(0) 
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
            ->setAttributeSetId(4) 
            ->setTypeId('simple') 
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) 
            ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) 

            ->setSku($pro->id) 
            ->setName($pro->name) 
            ->setWeight(4.000)
            ->setStatus(1) 
            ->setTaxClassId(4) 
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) 
            ->setManufacturer(2)
           // ->setColor(24)
            ->setNewsFromDate('10/26/2014') 
            ->setNewsToDate('12/30/2014') 
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('EG') 

            ->setPrice($pro->price) 
            ->setCost($pro->price+10)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) 
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) 

            ->setMetaTitle($pro->name)
            ->setMetaKeyword($pro->name)
            ->setMetaDescription($pro->description)

            ->setDescription($pro->description)
            ->setShortDescription($pro->description);

            $product->setStockData(array(
                               'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 
                               'manage_stock'=>1,
                               'min_sale_qty'=>1, 
                               'max_sale_qty'=>2, 
                               'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                               'qty' => 10
                           )
            )            
            ->setCategoryIds(array(21));
            $product->save();

$this->_addContent($block);
             $this->renderLayout();
```